# How come setitimeout function is access value of i even after the function call is over

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```js
function printSeries() {
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
   console.log(i);
  }, 3000);
 }
 console.log('printing');
}

printSeries();
```

How come it is printing value as i 10 times? SetTimeout callback function is being called after the stack is empty. Does it stores a lexical scope inside it

Comment: Your every execution is going to a timeout so after 3 sec all are printing and this is the way it does it. It doesn't cancel the execution it waits for the execution

Answer (score 2):

When the script reaches `setTimeout` for the first time, it adds your function to a queue to be executed after 3 seconds, and then *immediately* continues the loop.

By the time the 3 seconds have elapsed, the loop is long finished (10 iterations of a simple loop don't need 3 seconds), which is why you can see the `'printing'` message so early.

By this time, `i` is `10`, so `10` is printed 10 times (because this is the number of times that the function has been added to the queue. Javascript uses the current value of `i`, not the value of `i` at the time that the function was first added to the queue.

Here is an amended version of the script which uses the value of `i` at the time of adding the function to the queue:

```js
function printSeries() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    setTimeout((function(i) {
      return function() {
        console.log(i);
      }
    }(i)), 3000);

  }
  console.log('printing');
}

printSeries();
```

Here, the value of `i` is bound to the function, instead of just the reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am fine whether it is printing ten times 10 or 0 -9 in your amended version of yours. As we know setTimeout callbacks get picked up from event queue after the stacks get empty.  My question is var is functional level scope if the function has been finished how come value of i is accessible to the setTimeout function. Does is it have contextual reference of where the settimeout was created or there is some other concept.

Comment: `setTimeout` is called inside the function so it has access to the scope of the function. It does not matter whether the loop inside the function has finished or not.